# How removing commas in a list with strings, write in one line of code

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I have a List , x = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "cheese", "pear"] and I will write in one line of code that when executed returns "apples bananas carrots cheeses and pears".

Very Thanks for your help!

Comment: what did you try so far? Check `str.join()` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: When i write x.join() in my IDLE console a come : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @Wander Nauta , Thanks thas is was I to search! .I have with google to search and I have not to finde this answer.... so , thanks for the link .

Comment: @iratxe `x = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "cheese", "pear"] 
  print("\""+'s '.join(x[:-1])+"s"+" and "+(x[4])+"s"+"\"")`

Comment: @ yedpodtrzitko , I have yesterday five hours and today two hours in google to search , I writing "python removing commas  list of string" and all answer what i to find are not what to search ....

Comment: @Yousaf , thanks for you example , but as my knowledge about Python are very simple , for me the best answer is this:    print ", ".join(x[:-2] + [" and ".join(x[-2:])])  , I Understand well the Python Logic .....

Comment: @Yousaf , sorry for the before answer from me... you answer it is well , because this code :  print ", ".join(x[:-2] + [" and ".join(x[-2:])])    not print to ende , the word S , so , you answer it is the best!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Best answer is from Yousaf .

x = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "cheese", "pear"]

print("\""+'s '.join(x[:-1])+"s"+" and "+(x[4])+"s"+"\"")

Answer (score -1):

You need to use join just like octo has said

```
arr = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "cheese", "pear"]
my_string = " ".join(arr)
```

Well you can also do:

```
arr = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "cheese", "pear"]
my_string = ""
for ( n in range(len(arr) ):
  if n > 0:
    my_str += " " + arr[n]
  else:
    my_str += arr[n]
```

just to make my answer look different than others.